# Windows 2012 AD user failover to AWS Windows AD

Tags: windows, active-directory, amazon-web-services, failover

We're having a bit of an issue with our local Windows AD not failing over to our AWS hosted AD.

We have web portals for our support staff to log into with AD credentials. When our on-premise AD "fails" we are unable to authenticate with our AWS Windows AD controller.

Our Controllers replicate file storage and users, but I don't know where to look to troubleshoot authentication issues. I inherited this setup and unfortunately do not have contact with the admin that setup it up.

Could anyone point me to some doco about failover or logging or anything that may be helpful?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define "fails".  If during DC location the ldap bind succeeds there will be no subsequent location attempts for windows clients.  However you mention a web portal.  I suspect that your app is hard coded to look specifically at a single DC (probabaly an ldap bind)  rather than the domain. Check to see how your app is authenticating to the domain to determine the reason only 1 DC can be used.

Comment: We had our ISP go down last week and when that happened, none of our support staff was able to log into the web portal. We have a forest or domain between the on-prem AD and the one in the cloud and they replicate everyday (users, files, etc). The AD in the cloud should be able to authenticate users even if the on-prem one dies, but it doesn't seem to fail-over to that one. I'll check with the developers but I believe the web app is pointing to the one in the cloud.  Thank you.

Comment: Where is the web portal located? If it's in the cloud and your ISP connection goes down then I'd fully expect that you wouldn't be able to access it nor log into it.